# CCAnimation crashes with unrecognized selector setDisplayFrame

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I don't know why but my animation does not work.
I am trying to add an animated unit now via sprite sheet but through a set of sprites.
And something goes wrong
Here is the code of init method:

```
@implementation Enemy
-(id) initAt:(CGPoint)pos
{
    if([super init])
    {
        self.position = pos;
        CCSprite *start_sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"unit1_00000.png"];
        start_sprite.position  = ccp(0,0);
        [self addChild:start_sprite z:2];

        const int FRAMES_COUNT = 10;
        NSMutableArray* frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:FRAMES_COUNT];
        for (int i = 0; i < FRAMES_COUNT; i++)
        {
            NSString* file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"unit1_0000%i.png", i];
            CCTexture2D* texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:file];
            CGSize texSize = texture.contentSize;
            CGRect texRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, texSize.width, texSize.height);
            CCSpriteFrame* frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:texture rect:texRect];
            [frames addObject:frame];
        }


        _default_animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:0.1f];
        _current_anim_action = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:_default_animation];
        CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:_current_anim_action];
        [self runAction:repeat];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The error is the following: **-[Enemy setDisplayFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8929bd0**

Comment: Does `Enemy` extend `CCSprite`?

Comment: Then that's the problem. Please, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setDisplayFrame` is a method of `CCSprite` class, so in order to run a `CCAnimation` on `Enemy` class (which internally calls `setDisplayFrame`), `Enemy` must extend `CCSprite`, not `CCNode`.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason. Thank you :)